# Error opening a file in Python that's being constantly written to by an executable

Tags: python, executable, infinite

I am using Windows 10 and I have a python script that calls an executable file (C# app) that is constantly gathering data and writing that data into a .txt file. I can randomly open the .txt file and see that its data changes every time (what I want). After calling the executable, the python script attempts to open that same .txt file and read each line of it. However, my script is not continuing until I stop the executable - only then does it read the .txt file.

I am assuming because I can view the .txt file while the executable is running, that it is a python problem. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: reading it is fine, but trying to open a file to write that is already being written to may not be possible as the OS may prevent that as the file would be already opened elsewhere for writing.

Comment: you may also want to mention the operating system here. windows im guessing?

Comment: Paritosh - yes, sorry. Edited to say Win10. Thanks

Comment: so yeah, nope, not a python problem. Windows very aggressively blocks off file access when it is being written to, or opened anywhere in a handler that is capable of writing. More so than anything, it might be your C# code, and whether it releases the file handler or not.

Comment: I see. The C# app utilizes a StreamWriter object within a using statement (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)) to write each line into the .txt file. According to the link, the using statement should handle releasing the handler after each write.